# GCP error: Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've increased for my quota of NVIDIA K80, and received the request approval. Why am I still not able to use a VM with GPUs?

Error as shown in title.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Increasing the region-specific GPU quota won't work. GPUs(all regions) have to be increased from 0. Steps as of December 2018 are below:

1. From top left burger menu, select, IAM & admin -> Quotas.
   [image]
2. In filter type, select metric to be `GPUs(all regions)` and Location as `Global`
   [image]
3. Click edit quotas and new quota limit to 1 or more
   [image]

Comment: for those of you that are confused by the first image, you don't click "IAM" > "IAM" as he highlighted, you actually have to click "IAM" > "QUOTAS". Hope this saves someone from 15 minutes of confusion :)

Comment: You have to click Metrics "None" first, and then click GPU(all regions) to only see the GPU all regions. Thanks

Comment: I had my request denied. Any other solution so that I can run Parsec and play some ga mes?

Comment: I had my request denied as well. Any idea about why they denied?

Comment: I think the UI changed. Please look for limit name to be mentioned as GPUs (all regions). But I am unable to increase.. By the way as per this new plan, GPUs can not be used in Compute Engines in free tier https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

Comment: I struggled to find it under the IAM quotas: make sure to use the filter and type GPUs to find it

Comment: I tried this many times... And I have officially given up on GCP. After a full month of constance begging and escalation someone got back to me to tell me I had to yet again contact a "google cloud partner". I stopped after trying that and it didn't work out as well.They have informed me that they are not interested in "hobbyist/education" related allotment of GPU. I wrote my horrible experience with GCP on kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/208960

Answer (score 29):

I just came across this error and none of these directions were working for me (I think the GCP website has been updated since these answers).

In the filter at the top of the quotas page, I typed in Service: Compute Engine API and Limit Name: GPUs (all regions) and changed the limit from 0 to 1 or more. Hope this helps someone!

[image]

Comment: Or all you need to do is to click the upside-down triangle on top of the first checkbox. It will launch the configuration menu

Comment: @J.Oh  - your answers worked for me. GCP did change its console and therefore what you are saying is more relevant.

Comment: this also helped me in finding the right quota.

Comment: I would recommend changing the limit to exactly 1.

I tried changing it to 5, and I got rejected and told I needed to have "sales support" for that many.

Answer (score 17):

The top rated answer did not work out for me.

Here is what I did to get increase the global GPU quotas as of January 2021:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas
2. Filter by GPUs (All Regions)

[image]

3. Click on "Edit Quotas"

[image]

4. Requested limit 1 in the upcoming dialogue

[image]

5. Hit "Next" button
6. Filled the next form and hit "Submit Request" button

[image]

After these steps you have requested access to GPUs and should receive on your email account an email from Google Compute Engine Quota Support with either approval or denial of your quota increase request.

Comment: This answer is a working solution as of June 2021. Helped me to finally get GPU enabled notebook after 4 hours.

Comment: Agreed. This is the answer that helped me after a long period of trouble. The trick is to increase quota to exactly 1. More than that and the quota increase may be rejected.

Comment: You can also filter as `Quota: GPUs(all regions)` if above doesn't work.

Comment: After I've tried various approachs this one work for me (3/2022)

Answer (score 9):

Follow the instructions at [GCE Quota Increase](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6075746?hl=en&authuser=0).

Remember to select correct filters. If you're not sure or you don't see GPUs(all regions) (under the name "Compute Engine API", see the image) in the list, try to select all for those filters, and scroll through the list to look for it. It took me some time to realize this. In my case, it is listed in 601 - 716th items, almost at the last of the list.

Just select it and edit the quota according to you needs.
[image: GPUs(all regions)]

Answer (score 4):

You musty file a request that will include GPUS_ALL_REGIONS. New projects have a global GPU quota, which limits the total number of GPUs you can create in any supported zone. When you request a GPU quota, you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region, and an additional global quota for the total number of GPUs of all types in all zones. Please see this link[1] for more information.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions

Answer (score 3):

The provided answers did not work for me. After searching for "GPUs (all regions)", there was no checkbox next to the filtered results. Clicking on the results and then clicking "edit quotas" as suggested did nothing.

Instead, here is the ridiculous process I had to go through:

1. As with other answers, go to the Quotas page and filter for `GPUs (all regions)`.
2. Click `All Quotas` in the `Details` field of the result.
3. A new table appears with only a single entry. The checkbox is grayed out.
4. Instead of selecting and editing Quotas, click `View hierarchy` in the last field of the entry.
5. A new table should appear with all of your projects.
6. Finally, the checkboxes are not grayed out. Select the appropriate project.
7. NOW you can click `Edit Quotas`.

Google. WTF mate? Now, according to one answer you should do the same for the regions you want to use.

Comment: Also had this problem. Are you using the free tier? "GPUs and TPUs are not included in the Free Tier offer. You are always charged for GPUs and TPUs that you add to VM instances." https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

Comment: @Wes hey, my names Wes too! And I may be. Previously was using my personal account, but started using a G-Suite account provided by my new job. I have no idea if it's the free tier or not (I'm pretty sure my personal account was, and I got a GPU quota just fine without having to request it).

Comment: the checkbox was also grayed out for me until I upgraded to a trial account with $300 credit

Answer (score 0):

Also, GCP error message does not make sense. For example, it kept on showing me the above error message even after I got the global quota increased. Later I found out from this documentation:-
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions

.. that the above GPU configuration is not supported with the particular  Intel Skylake or later CPU platforms. Error message never talks about this incompatibility issue ( under the notification). It still says:

```
    Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally
```

folks@GCP should improve the error messaging.

Comment: 100% it has to improve.. It is the worst... I was waiting 5 hrs for a VM to initiate when later I was informed by the support that this is because I don't have GPU allotted. How about a simple message instead of wasting 5 hrs...

Comment: Still terrible in 2023, don't know what this absurdly paid Google engineers are doing, but it doesn't show :S