# Getting denied for quota increase Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have recently created a new account for GCP to test out deep learning in the cloud. However I keep getting denied for an increase of quota.

I think my account has already been upgraded as I dont seen an upgrade option at the top of Dashboard. I think I remember clicking on the "upgrade" button when I had first created the account. **I am not sure how exactly to make sure my account has been upgraded.** 
I only see the icons for "activate cloud shell" etc etc on the dashboard.

I have followed this link to request for increase in quota:

[GCP error: Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415180/gcp-error-quota-gpus-all-regions-exceeded-limit-0-0-globally)

to request for  increase to 1 GPU.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you have put a real credit card on your account with correct billing information that has credit available. If Google has denied you, why do you think we can approve you? In regards to upgrading accounts, spend time learning about how billing works with GCP. This might save you money when you do get quotas increased.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the reply. I currently had a banking account (it was autolinked to my google account), so I switched to a credit card and will see how that goes. Also, I was told to contact this email via their response mail, gc-team@google.com for customer support, but no one has responsed for 4 days or so. Is there a different email address I should be contacting?

Comment: That was a good decision. If you read the billing documentation, you will read that you must use a real credit card / debit card that is in your name (or the company's) or a verfied checking account. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-bank You cannot use prepaid debit cards (the ones without a name) and other non-typical payment methods.