# Account upgrade at Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I know my account is still in free-trial or upgraded?
I can't setup GPU instance and always have `"Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally."` error. I need to upgrade my account.

But I can't find `Upgrade button or Free-Trial status button` as discussed in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier).

Comment: In the Google Cloud Console go to Billing and set up your credit card. Details on your account are there. Even with a credit card on file, you can still use Free Trial and Always Free products/services and you will not get charged for them. You will be charged for services not part of those offerings.

Comment: In addition to @JohnHanley, regardless of free-tier or paid GCP you will need to fix/update your Quotas. Similar question from the past with answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415180/gcp-error-quota-gpus-all-regions-exceeded-limit-0-0-globally

Comment: Hi @StéphaneFréchette - Nice link.

Comment: Google Cloud Platform Support here. @JohnHanley, since you were the one who provided the initial information, could you post this as an answer? So it gets more visibility to users who might also have the same issue.

Comment: To know your support package, go to Navigation Menu --> Support --> Overview, there's a support info section in that page which shows your support package, click the "--> Upgrade" if you would like to upgrade your support package. And YES, you need to upgrade to bronze or above if you would like to use GPU since you won't be able to add GPU when you're on free trial https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

Comment: I added my credit card and all, and I'm STILL not allowed to use GPUs, the GPUS all regions won't allow me to increase the gpu limit from zero.

Comment: The upgrade message never showed for me in Firefox, but it showed up when I used Chrome. So seems like you need to use the Google browser for the cloud console to work correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#to_upgrade_your_account), you must go to the top of the page and click the upgrade button:

> You can upgrade from the free trial to a paid account through the Google Cloud Platform Console. Click the Upgrade button at the top of the page. If you do not see Upgrade, click Free trial status Free trial status icon in the upper-right of the page and Upgrade will appear.
>
> You must be a Billing Administrator on the account to make this change.

Also @StéphaneFréchette shared another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415180/gcp-error-quota-gpus-all-regions-exceeded-limit-0-0-globally) in which the steps needed in order to increase the GPU Quota for `GPUS_ALL_REGIONS`. The steps needed are:

- Navigate to Quotas inside the IAM menu
- In filter type, select metric to be GPUs(all regions) and select Location as Global
- Click edit quotas and new quota limit to 1 or more