# GPU Quota Error even when i have Quota for Nvidia P100 both for region Us-west1 and Europe-west4 from 0 to 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just made up a account on Google Cloud Platform and am trying to make a VM instance and have even increased my GPU quota in region Us-west1 and Europe-west4 both to 1 from 0

Yet when i try to create a VM instance using Nvidia P100
Its gives me the error - Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally

Any help would be appreciated please and if that GPU is not usable then can you advise on a similar powered GPU please

Answer (score 1):

As the error says you need to increase the ALL_REGIONS quota, take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415180/gcp-error-quota-gpus-all-regions-exceeded-limit-0-0-globally)

From Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus):

"Similar to virtual CPU quota, GPU quota refers to the total number of virtual GPUs in all VM instances in a region. Check the quotas page to ensure that you have enough GPUs available in your project, and to request a quota increase. In addition, **new accounts and projects have a global GPU quota that applies to all regions.**

When you request a GPU quota, you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region, **and an additional global quota for the total number of GPUs of all types in all zones.**"

*I assume you upgraded your billing account already as it is a requirement to use GPUs.

Comment: yes i upgraded my account but the problem is this - 
I tried to make a VM instance earlier but failed even when i requested quota three times ,it failed because i did not raise quota of All Regions with error report coming back as Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally.

My VM instance GPU im trying to use is P100 us-west1b and still get this error, i cant increase the quota and now i cant make a VM instance with a GPU 
And this is my first VM instance and a new account ,now how do i create a VM instance with a GPU now as they say something about account history they need

Comment: having an "account history" will only make the quota increase process faster but it is not absolutely required (the first time you request it you won't have a history). Did you look into the Stack Overflow question I posted? It has a screenshot for the specific quota you need to request. When you request any quota a ticket is open automatically with Google and it is usually processed within 72 hours (automatically) you will get an email saying the same but if you reply to that very same email a support agent will take a look and respond to you